# How to turn Cursor into CursorLoader?

Tags: java, android

I have a little problem with SQLite and ContentProviders. First of all here is my current code:

```
public void loadFavoriteMovies(){
    movieList.clear();
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(FavoriteMoviesContract.MovieEntry.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, FavoriteMoviesContract.MovieEntry._ID);


    if(cursor != null){
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {

            MovieResults.Movie movie = new MovieResults.Movie(
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FavoriteMoviesContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_TITLE)),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FavoriteMoviesContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_IMAGE)),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FavoriteMoviesContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_BACKDROP)),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FavoriteMoviesContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_RELEASE)),
                    Double.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FavoriteMoviesContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_RATING))),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FavoriteMoviesContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_PLOT)),
                    Integer.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FavoriteMoviesContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_ID)))
                    );

            movieList.add(movie);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }


    Log.v("Size of Favorites:", String.valueOf(movieList.size()));
    mAdapter.setmMovieList(movieList);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is I'm reading the SQLite database and putting the values there into a Movie object. But my problem is I want to do this operation using CursorLoader. How can I achieve this?

My main aim for doing this is because Cursor does not automatically update the value when I delete an item from the database and I need to reload the activity which the items are displayed. If anyone can offer an alternative way, that'd also be appreciated.

Comment: You can just put a listener on delete operation to update the displayed items.

Comment: What kind of listener? I'm not experienced in Android that much can you please explain in a bit more detail? Thanks :)

Comment: Run a method to notify you activity that there are changes made in db so it can update the UI.